# std::any implementation details

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Looking at `std::any` implementation it is very strange why access through `aligned_storage` for small objects is implemented with `const`. What is the purpose of this? It is to do with something that `aligned_storage` may store `const` objects? If so where does the standard backs this up?

**Link to the latest `std::any` implementation in libstdc++**

https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/a90bd3ea6d1ba27b15476f0a768d7952c6723420/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/any#L392

```
static _Tp* _S_access(const _Storage& __storage)
{ 
   // The contained object is in __storage._M_buffer
  const void* __addr = &__storage._M_buffer;
  return static_cast<_Tp*>(const_cast<void*>(__addr));

}
```

Appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: I don't see this as being related to the standard in any way.  It might just be some sort of (private!) gcc trick to get around strict aliasing rules.

Comment: aliasing should not be of concern as std::any got protection against it in their any_cast function, so only the right type can access the object with cv been accounted and allowed through aliasing rules

Comment: well, technically std::launder is missing there. Is that an alternative to it?

Comment: libc++ does not use the const trick so must be indeed something gcc, but interesting what. https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/78d6a7767ed57b50122a161b91f59f19c9bd0d19/include/any#L403

Comment: I guess it's done this way simply to avoid code duplication for `const _Storage&` and `_Storage&` parameters - you can always pass by `const _Storage&`. Const-correctness for returned `_Tp*` is on a user, but it's OK for internal functions.

Comment: @Evg oh yes that makes sense! although they did not do it for dynamically allocated objects.  https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/a90bd3ea6d1ba27b15476f0a768d7952c6723420/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/any#L423

Comment: For `_M_buffer` you take its address and the resulting pointer gets `const` from `__storage`. For `_M_ptr` you take its value and it doesn't care about const-ness of `__storage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no trick here, it's just simplicity of implementation - to avoid code duplication.

You need both `const` and non-`const` versions of this function with essentially the same implementation. It's easy to write only one version and put const-correctness burden on a user - this is an internal function, so that user is a library implementer and they know what they are doing.

For both statically and dynamically allocated objects `_S_access()` takes `__storage` by `const&`, so that you could pass both `const _Storage&` and `_Storage&`.

For statically allocated objects,

```
static _Tp*
_S_access(const _Storage& __storage)
{
  // The contained object is in __storage._M_buffer
  const void* __addr = &__storage._M_buffer;
  return static_cast<_Tp*>(const_cast<void*>(__addr));
}
```

when an address of `_Storage`'s data member `_M_buffer` is taken, it [automatically gets `const` qualification](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.type.qualifier#1.1), so we need to cast it away.

For dynamically allocated ones,

```
static _Tp*
_S_access(const _Storage& __storage)
{
  // The contained object is in *__storage._M_ptr
  return static_cast<_Tp*>(__storage._M_ptr);
}
```

we read `_M_ptr` data member of type `void*`. No `const` is propagated into that `void*`, so no `const_cast` is needed. Const-correctness is still on a user.

Comment: formal proof by the standard: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.type.qualifier#1.1

Comment: @minex Added link into the answer, thank you.